# Img expand to 100% on click (and still stick to grid)

Tags: javascript, html, css, image, grid

This is what I'm working with:
http://jsfiddle.net/wppjq1a3/

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('.sec-img').click(function() {
        $(this).css({
            height: '100%',
            width: '100%'
        });
    });
});
```

What I would like it to do is following:

- When you click on any image, it expands (if there is one image above
  the expanded image; then the small image will be pushed under the
  expanded image.
- Also when you click on one image, the previous expanded one contracts
  to the original size (50%).
- I would like to work with some grid of kind. The images are all going
  to have the same size ratio. I've tried to work with :after to get
  this two column grid with 20px between (bottom and middle) every
  image, but with no results.

Answer (score 0):

Give this a try:

```
http://jsfiddle.net/wppjq1a3/2/
```

instead of adding css into the jquery, I toggled a class. I added a background color of red so that when you differentiate on the hover because the opacity gets turned down, and I wanted to be sure that the div I was clicking appeared in the front. I also added an absolute position, and a z-

jQuery:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('.sec-img').click(function() {
        $(this).toggleClass("expand");
    });
});
```

CSS:

```
.expand{
    width:100% !important;
    height:100% !important;
    position: absolute;
    z-index:999999 !important;

}
```